# Sort DF based on Series with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, series

I have a few dataframes with some values, like such:

DF 1:

| Number | Fruit | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | banana | car |
| 300 | apple | bus |
| 400 | kiwi | truck |
| 330 | house | bike |

and I am trying to sort them based on a series.

Series 1:

| Number |
| --- |
| 300 |
| 400 |
| 330 |
| 100 |

This generally works if I do the following:

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index('Number')
df_1 = df_1.loc[series_1]
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()
```

Now the only issue is that my series might be LONGER than the DF and contain some nan values, like such:

Series 2:

| Number |
| --- |
| 300 |
| nan |
| 400 |
| 330 |
| 100 |

What this produces is the following sort:

DF 1 - sort false:

| Number | Fruit | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | apple | bus |
| 400 | kiwi | truck |
| 330 | house | bike |
| 100 | banana | car |

But what I hoped it would produce, to preserve the size of the original series would be the below. This is important since I stack them horizontally with other DFs later and if one of the series rows gets dropped, that will not work anymore.

DF 1 - sort right:

| Number | Fruit | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | apple | bus |
| nan | nan | nan |
| 400 | kiwi | truck |
| 330 | house | bike |
| 100 | banana | car |

Any ideas on how to achieve this cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) instead of [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
out = (df_1.set_index('Number')
           .reindex(series_1)
           .reset_index()
       )
```

Alternatively, you can also [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) after converting the Series [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
out = pd.merge(series_1.to_frame(name='Number'), df, how='left')
```

Output:

```
   Number   Fruit   Type
0   300.0   apple    bus
1     NaN     NaN    NaN
2   400.0    kiwi  truck
3   330.0   house   bike
4   100.0  banana    car
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution here with reindex worked well. The merge solution did unfortunately not, I had some issues with the to_frame function.